# What would the conversion of this from EBNF to BNF be? Also, what is the leftmost derivation?

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I need to convert this from EBNF to BNF.

```
<statement> ::= <ident> = <expr>
<statement> ::= IF <expr> THEN <statement> [ ELSE <statement> ] END
<statement> ::= WHILE <expr> DO <statement> END
<statement> ::= BEGIN <statement> {; <statement>} END
```

Also, I'm stuck on this one:

```
E -> E+T | E-T | T
T -> T*F | T/F | F
F -> (E) | VAR | INT
VAR -> a | b | c
INT -> 0 | 1 | 2| 3 | 4| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
```

> After modifying the grammer to add a `^` operator,  What is the leftmost derivation that your grammar assigns to the expression `a^2^b*(c+1)?` You may find it convenient to sketch the parse tree for this expression first, and then figure out the leftmost derivation from that.

I added `G -> F^G | G` and then got `G 2 G b E` as my answer but am not sure if that is correct.